# Launching Windows Explorer and highlighting a file

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to open a Windows Explorer window using VBA, navigate to a specific file mentioned in active cell of the Excel sheet, and select it.

For example, Column `A` has file names to search for and if I select column `A1` and run the macro, it should open the path/directory and find the file mentioned in `A1` and only select the file. It should not open it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute `explorer.exe` with the `/select` argument:

```
Shell "explorer.exe /select,""" & Range("A1") & """", vbNormalFocus
```

Assuming `A1` had the path `c:\path\to\file.txt`, this would look like:

```
explorer.exe /select,"c:\path\to\file.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you! But if we want the file name to be the active cell i.e the cell which is selected instead of A1  then what changes we need to do??

Comment: Just use `ActiveCell` in place of `Range("A1")`.

Comment: I used the below syntax: `Shell "explorer.exe /select, V:\Jul\1st Jul\File.pdf" & ActiveCell & """", vbNormalFocus`. This is opening the users folder when i select the activeCell. Kindly help me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Why are you using a file path AND `ActiveCell`? I thought your file path was IN `ActiveCell`?

Comment: Just a heads up notice the coma after /select.  It took me a while to realize my error as usually a space is fine between a switch like that

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

The below will bring up the explorer window with the correct results and finds all files with the word experience in it in the path SSDrive.

Call Shell("explorer.exe ""search-ms://query=Experience&crumb=folder:" & sSDrive & """")

@ https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/a8a0daef-a2e2-4559-a209-d2f263a52b05/searchms-output-results-to-file?forum=windowsdesktopsearchhelp